# “Getting something down” in this context

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I know getting something down has many different meanings in different contexts. I think I am familiar will most of them, if not all.

What does it mean in this context?

> I told him where he should place his foot, but the rest is all down to him. He has **got** **it** **down** to a tee

Reference article : https://www.goal.com/en-in/news/messi-ronaldo-maradona-di-stefano-best-player-history/1fuo0t9cdjpv31jwx6xu1469wb

This is not the first time I have come across this phrasal verb being used in this context. Although I could figure out the meaning from the context (that the said soccer player has perfected his ability), I want to know what **Get something down** in this context means.

I tried looking it up in many reputed online dictionaries, but none of the explanations seemed to match the meaning of **Get sth down** in this context. If possible, please refer to how an online dictionary explains the meaning of this phrasal verb in this context. Thanks

Comment: I think it's actually '*he has got it || [down to a tee](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/down-to-a-t)*'

Comment: I haven't made any effort to check, but my guess is that to have something ***down to a T*** derives from (or is somehow related) ***to dot the I's and cross the T's*** (to do something *exactly* right, down to the smallest details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've highlighted only part of the idiom. The phrase is "**down to a tee**" (also sometimes styled, possibly wrongly, as "*down to a T*").

> [to a tee](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+a+tee)
>   Perfectly; completely; exactly. More commonly seen as "to a T." The origin of the phrase is uncertain.

It is *normally* used to indicate *suitability* for something, for example, "*the job suited him down to a tee*".

In the context of your quotation, a similar idiom is more commonly used: "*[get it down pat](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+it+down+pat)*". Possibly the author of your quote mixed up the two.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. You said they might have mixed up the two idioms. So what would be the right way to say that if I just want to use the first idiom? “He has learned it down to a tee” ?

Comment: @πtimese It *might* be right to use either, I'm just way more used to seeing "it *suited* him down to a *tee*" and "he has *got* it down *pat*". If you Google the expressions you'll find some examples. Google Books will show you published examples.